# How can I create multiple users in Unix?

Tags: users

Someone tell me a way to create multiple users in UNIX. If I want to write a script, how can I do it? Any advice?

Comment: With eunuchs, you're limited to creating new users asexually—with `useradd` or `adduser`.

Comment: Did you find any answers to your question by searching online first?

Comment: Yes, but I need to learn shell  scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint to get you started:

```
#!/bin/sh

for username; do
    # to-do
done
```

You can pass multiple usernames to this script, and it will execute the command inside the for loop for each of them, for example:

```
./create-many.sh alice bob john
```

You just have to complete the content of the for loop. This should get you started.

Or if you have a file with one username per line then:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read username; do
    # to-do
done < /path/to/file
```

Comment: Tank you ,I'm going to write this script , it will read from file contains 100 of users with passwords and create them all, that's the goal of my idea

Comment: I added a bit more info for the case of reading usernames from a file

Comment: Tank you again, it really helped me out

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your script for you but you need to write a "wrapper" script for `useradd` that will pass the required flags and variables in to the command.